# get map from jsp-form spring

Tags: java, post, spring-mvc

I am new in Spring MVC, and I have a problem.

I'm sending to FORM **LinkedHashMap**, and it's showing great.

```
model.addAttribute("resultForm", resultForm);
```

Part of my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${resultForm}" var="resultMap" varStatus="status">
                        <tr id="tableRow" class="table-row">
                            <td>
                                ${resultMap.key}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <select name="resultMap['${resultMap.key}']" class="espa-config-select">
                                <option selected value ="${resultMap.value}">${resultMap.value}</option>
                                <c:forEach items="${mainParams}" var="item2">
                                    <c:if test="${item2.key == resultMap.key}">
                                        <c:forEach items="${item2.value}" var = "q">
                                            <c:if test="${resultMap.value != q}">
                                                <option value="${q}"> ${q} </option>
                                            </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Now I need to get it back

Here is part of Controller

```
@RequestMapping( value = "espa/update", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("resultForm") LinkedHashMap<String,String> resultForm) {
        System.out.println("resultMap post "+resultForm.toString());
        if (resultForm!=null){
            //resultForm.put("Port", port);
            espaService.setConfiguration(selectedDevice, resultForm);
            LOG.debug("Saving configuration: {} /nPort{}",resultForm, selectedDevice);

       }

        return "redirect:/espa";
    }
```

But it is empty!
How can I fix it?

Comment: Please reformulate your question, I can't understand a word.

Comment: Also add some sample code, please.

Comment: Changed question and added some code

Answer (score 0):

In your select you are using the name "resultMap".  The name attribute needs to correlate to the Model Attribute, which you are called "resultForm".

Comment: Forgot to mention, since I can't see the whole JSP, or at least the whole <form> tag, its hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish.  Also, you may find it easier to use the JSTL tags Spring MVC provides.